# Sort value and calculate difference for multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe like this, where `place1` and `place2` are the indexes, I want to sort index `place2` by `data` value, without disrupt the order of index `place1`, that is, the `place2` column becomes `a, c, b` for each `place1`. Is there a way to do this?

```
place1 place2 data
 sss     a    100
         b    300
         c    200
 ses     a    400
         b    600
         c    500
  ...   ...   ...
```

I also want to calculate the `data` difference between `place2 == b` and `place2 == a` for each `place1`, that is, the dataframe becomes

```
place1 place2 data diff
 sss     a    100  200
         b    300
         c    200
 ses     a    400  200
         b    600
         c    500
  ...   ...   ...  ...
```

Is there an efficient way to calculate the difference like this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.groupby()` and then calculate the diff of each group:

```
groups = df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False, sort=False)
df['diff'] = groups.transform(lambda x: x.xs('b', level='place2').iloc[0] - x.xs('a', level='place2').iloc[0])
```

It adds the value to each row of the group - but you can remove the "duplicates" afterwards if needed.

```
>>> df
               data  diff
place1 place2            
sss    a        100   200
       b        300   200
       c        200   200
ses    a        400   200
       b        600   200
       c        500   200
```

You can then sort the `data` column within each group

```
>>> groups.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('data'))
               data  diff
place1 place2            
sss    a        100   200
       c        200   200
       b        300   200
ses    a        400   200
       c        500   200
       b        600   200
```